# How to extend a class inside a namespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces, prototype, extend

```
var sl = sl || {}

sl.Shape = function(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
};
sl.Shape.prototype.move = function(x,y){
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
};
sl.Rectangle = function(){
    sl.Shape.call(this);
    this.z = 0;
};
```

The next line produces the error (Object prototype undefined, has to be Object or null). As far as I can see this is because Shape is "namespaced".

```
sl.Rectangle.protoype = Object.create(sl.Shape.protoype);
sl.Rectangle.protoype.constructor = sl.Rectangle;
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use word prototype instead protoype.

Comment: thanks, took me until 4 am to see it, even in what you wrote!!

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the word "prototype" as Andrii pointed out, try this example:

```
(function() {
  var sl = sl || {};

  function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }

  Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  };

  function Rectangle() {
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
    this.z = 0;
  };

  Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
  Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

  sl.Shape = Shape;
  sl.Rectangle = Rectangle;

  // expose
  window.sl = sl;
}());
```

Usage

```
var shape = new sl.Shape();
var rect = new sl.Rectangle();
```